# Multiple Depot Vehicle Routing Problem Optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner, np-hard, vehicle-routing, optaweb-vehicle-routing

I am trying to customize **Optaplanner** for my particular use-case. I have been successful so far but now I am struck at the point where I need to have **multiple depot and multiple location**. Their main use-case seems to be under the assumption that `all the vehicle will start from a particular location` called depot/warehouse.

In my use-case the conditions are slightly different, The vehicle can start from their own **respective locations**, meaning there will be **multiple depot and multiple customer locations** to visit. {**MDVRP problem**}

**for e.g ->**

```
       If I have 5 agent and 10 customer location to provide any service, this algorithm assumes 
       that all these agent will start from same starting location i.e warehouse/depot. 
       Thus the algorithm will optimize routes based on this assumption and all routes will 
       start from warehouse
```

**My use case is somewhat like this**

```
    If I have 5 agent and 10 customer location to provide any service. Then the algorithm should 
    start optimizing the route from their own respective location to all the customer location.
```

So far I have tried custom input to their algorithm. But it doesn't work in an expected manner. Have anyone tried this tool with multiple depot. Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The `optaplanner-examples` implementation supports multi-depot's and it has datasets with multidepots in [its data directory](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/tree/master/optaplanner-examples/data/vehiclerouting/import/belgium). The OptaWeb implementation is based on that model, so the solver should be able to handle it already, but the UI doesn't support this feature yet.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I was searching for multiple-depot in optaweb project. I did find the multiple depot data that you mentioned in the original project. However I was still unable to do the same in Optaweb Implementation. The original optaplanner have the multi-depot functionality but the optaweb doesn't. If you know how multi-depot can be used in Optaweb , Please do share the info.